# JPA @ElementCollection generates strange unique key

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity class PositionOrdering which contains an element collection:

```
@ElementCollection(targetClass = Position.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "POSITION_ORDERING_POSITION", 
     joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "position_ordering_id"))
@OrderColumn
List<Position> positions = new ArrayList<>();
```

When hibernate generates the database structure, it looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE wls.position_ordering_position
(
    position_ordering_id bigint NOT NULL,
    positions_id bigint NOT NULL,
    positions_order integer NOT NULL,
    ...
}
```

It's ok and exactly what I was expected. **But it also generate a unique contsraint on `positions_id` column.** It is strange, because the position id should be unique only per ordering, so any of the following unique keys would be ok:

- position_ordering_id + positions_order
- position_ordering_id + positions_id

But not on the single column of positions_id.

Because the constraint is generated automatically, I can't ignore or remove it simply.

Can I configure my collection to create correct unique constraint or at least not to create any?

**UPDATE:**

As for request, here is the skeleton of the Position entity:

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = EntityBase.SEQUENCE_NAME, 
       sequenceName = "POSITION_ID_SEQ")
@Table(name = "position")
public class Position extends EntityBase {

    // Lots of fields, like row, column number, and type, etc.
}
```

Where EntityBase is a simple class with some utility function and with Id:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class EntityBase implements Serializable, Cloneable {

    public static final String SEQUENCE_NAME = "SEQUENCE_GENERATOR";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = SEQUENCE_NAME)
    protected Long id;

     //..
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code of `Position` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@ElementCollection` is used for mapping basic types or `@Embedded` classes, not entities. From [the documentation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection)

> An *ElementCollection* can be used to define a one-to-many relationship to an Embeddable object, or a Basic value (such as a collection of Strings).

Since `Position` is an `@Entity`, you should map it as `@OneToMany` or `@ManyToMany`. I don't know the exact reason why are you getting that unique key generated, but I guess you can expect unpredictable results if you use the annottion in a was that it was not intended for.

Answer (score 0):

As Predrag Maric described it in the accepted answer, the problem was that Position was not an `Embeddable'. My solution was:

I created a support class which wraps the Position into an @Embeddable entity:

```
@Embeddable
//@Table(name = "position_ordering_position")
public class PositionOrderingPosition {

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name = "position_id", nullable = false)
   private Position position;

   public PositionOrderingPosition() {
   }

   public PositionOrderingPosition(Position position) {
       this.position = position;
   }

    public Position getPosition() {
        return position;
    }
}
```

Also I changed the Element collection to this:

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "POSITION_ORDERING_POSITION", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "position_ordering_id"))
@OrderColumn
List<PositionOrderingPosition> positions = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now it creates the same table, but with the right constraints.